# SQL Server : display column with each data set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm exporting data out to a flat file to import into a SIEM. Is there a way to display as "column name = data" for each item?

```
SELECT 
    [Description], [MessageDescription], [CardNumber], 
    [TimeStamp_Server], [SPMDescription] [CardHolderID], 
    [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName],
    [CardStatusID], [CardStatusDescription], [Imprint],
    [TransactionNumber]
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[Message]
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), TimeStamp_Server, 120) = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Here is how it currently presents in the flat file.

```
Description,MessageDescription,CardNumber,TimeStamp_Server,CardHolderID,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,CardStatusID,CardStatusDescription,Imprint,TransactionNumber
North Entry,AccessGrantedNoEntry,0,2023-02-08 09:52:19,Retail Center C004 Converted PXL250-2DOOR,,,,,,,527312
```

I'd like it to display as this for each row

```
Description = North Entry,
MessageDescription = AccessGrantedNoEntry,
CardNumber = 0, 
TimeStamp_Server = 2023-02-08
```

... and so on.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: I think you are looking for UNPIVOT or an EAV, but without proper formatting, your question is unreadable.

Comment: The problem isn't the SQL. The problem is writing out the file, and we don't see any of that code.

Comment: Also, converting to varchar is about the worst possible way to compare if the date values of two datetimes are equal.

Comment: I'm using the SQL server import and export wizard so I don't know what code you want to see for writing out the file.

Comment: Is there a better way to get only today's date? That was the best I could find that worked.

Comment: I'm still confused if the desired results is one long string or is it supposed to be rows

Comment: It looks like you just want a single column for each row, have you considered `concat`?

Comment: I'm fine with rows or string. I want the column name = data in that column for each row.  I'm trying to import it into a SIEM because the program that uses this data doesn't support exporting logs.

Comment: I've never seen a SIEM that couldn't handle CSV data, but even so: again, this isn't really an SQL issue at all. The issue is in the client code or tool creating the file, after the SQL has already finished.

Comment: So you want every column name reproduced on every row? That's going to significantly increase the size of the file! Just use `select concat('columnName = ', ColumnName)Columename, ...`

Comment: I think you can utilise the suggested answer from @JohnCappelletti which generates your data with a lot less typing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Stu for providing what I was seeking [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389556/sql-server-display-column-with-each-data-set/75389854#comment133024557_75389556):

> So you want every column name reproduced on every row? That's going to significantly increase the size of the file! Just use
>
> ```
> select concat('columnName = ', ColumnName)Columename, ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a side issue (so community wiki), but you can **significantly** improve performance of this query by changing the `WHERE` clause like this (assuming `TimeStamp_Server` is a `DateTime` column):

```
WHERE TimeStamp_Server >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) 
    AND TimeStamp_Server < cast(dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date)) as datetime)
```

This helps in three ways:

1. Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting dates to and from string values is far slower and more error-prone than we'd like to believe. Sticking with Date functions and types will always perform better and be more accurate.
2. By shifting all the modifications to `getdate()`, so `TimeStamp_Server` is unaltered, we avoid needing to do the conversion on **every row in the table**.
3. By shifting all the modifications to `getdate()`, so `TimeStamp_Server` is unaltered, we preserve the use of any index that might exist for the column. This cuts to the core of database performance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works to improve that part.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of JSON and `string_agg()`

```
Select B.NewVal
From ( 
       --Your Query Here-- 
     ) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select NewVal = string_agg(concat([key],' = ',value),',')
                 From openjson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  ) )
              ) B
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

Please try the following conceptual example.

IMHO, the JSON or XML output format would be much more reliable.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, case_date DATE, Product INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (id, case_date, Product) VALUES
(55, '2022-08-01', 11),
(66, '2022-05-21', 51);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , result = STUFF(XMLData.query('
        for $x in /root/*
        return concat(", ", local-name($x), "=", $x/text()[1])
        ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(4096)'), 1,2,'')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(XMLData);
```

**Output**

| id | case_date | Product | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2022-08-01 | 11 | id=55 , case_date=2022-08-01 , Product=11 |
| 66 | 2022-05-21 | 51 | id=66 , case_date=2022-05-21 , Product=51 |